# How does the max function work on python sets?

Tags: python, set

Code:

```
test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4] 
print(max(set(test), key = test.count))
```

Result:

```
4
```

In the above code, how does it work overall?

My understanding is, after the list `test` is converted to a set, all duplicate elements are lost. Then how does the `max` function find the value with the most occurances in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `set(test)` doesn't change what's in the `test` variable. It still contains the list with all the duplicates. This just filters out the duplicates in the first argument to `max()` (to minimize the number of times it calls `test.count()`), but the `key` function is able to count them in the original list.

The problem you describe would occur if you reassigned `test`, as in:

```
test = set(test)
print(max(test, key=test.count))
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar ! This is a new kind of implementation I came across & I was reading it as max being applied to set(test) rather than the actual list test & also that max function is no where referring to raw test variable (which has all the values) . Are there more example that you can share that could help understand this implementation better ?

Comment: `max()` *is* being applied to `set(test)`. But the `key` function is using the original `test` list, not the set.